# jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-events

I'd like to build a multi-select widget as shown on this page, it features unique selection, menu always open for easy selection with mouse.

Source and markup available here [if you're unfamiliar with jsFiddle just comment on the question to let me know]:
http://jsfiddle.net/ahmedkhalaf/khPn7/

when you click to select an item, the menu is updated with items excluding selected ones.

The problem is I need to move the mouse around to another item to be able to select items again, It seems you cant re-trigger `focus` and `mousedown` events on the new items without leaving the item.

This only happens on Firefox, on IE8 I can select all items with just keep clicking the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching a click event to each option where the event appends the option's value to the tags container, focuses on the option's parent, then removes the option?

```
$("select#idOfSelect option").click(function(){
    $("div#idOfContainer").append( $(this).val() );
    $(this).parent().focus();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: and just canceling the jQuery autocomplete "select" even ? this will be GREAT :) I will try this idea and get back to you, thanks :)